# how do I break while loop if a condition is not met?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a check for a loop whether it is infinite or not. This is what I'm trying to do, but can't make this work. How do I break the loop?

```
function isInfiniteProcess(a, b) {
    while (a !== b) {
      a++;
      b--;
    }
}

isInfiniteProcess(2, 3)
```

How do I end this loop if it is infinite?

Comment: C'mon, be honest.. Did you come to the conclusion that this had really never, ever been asked before, and you genuinely couldn't think of anything to Google for, to get an answer? I get that sometimes things are tough to Google etc, but "how do I break out of a JavaScript while loop?" must surely be a faster route to an answer, and it's virtually what you asked here..

Comment: You are the legend. You are wasting more time writing this than me waiting for the answer. Dudes below helped me with solutions that I couldn't find before I created this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop will always go to infinite if a becomes greater than b.
so to Exit the while loop you can use break like this:

```
 function isInfiniteProcess(a, b) {
     while (a !== b) {
          a++;
          b--;
         if(a > b) break;
      }
      if(a > b) return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a check (kind of hacky) that I've seen being used. It uses `Date` to keep track of the time a loop is using. It doesn't check if a loop is really infinite or not, it just checks wether it taking too long or not:

```js
function isInfiniteProcess(a, b) {
    var t0 = Date.now();
    while (a !== b) {
      a++;
      b--;

      if(Date.now() - t0 > 5000) {       // if this loop keeps running for 5 seconds and not finished yet
        return true;                     // break it and return true
      }
    }
    return false;                        // otherwise return false (the loop finished before 5 seconds has passed)
}

if(isInfiniteProcess(2, 3))
    console.log("The loop may be infinite...");
```

This isn't really reliable, but it helps detect if a loop could be infinite. The threshold (here `5` seconds) is totally up to you to choose.

**Note:** As @snap mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877733/how-do-i-break-while-loop-if-a-condition-is-not-met/47877810#comment82721573_47877810) bellow, you can use an iterations counter instead of time delta:

```
var counter = 0;
while(...) {
    ...
    if(++counter > 1000000) {      // after the 1000000th iteration
        return true;               // assume the loop is infinite and break it
    }
}
```

As for the other approach, the threshhold (here `1000000` iterations) is really up to you to choose.

Comment: same approach would also works with a counter and a max value.

Comment: @snap Great idea! I'm adding this as a note.